# How can I change media root of photologue in Django

Tags: python, django, heroku, photologue

I am trying to deploy a project on Heroku, the build is successful.
Here's the build log

```
-----> Python app detected
-----> Installing requirements with pip
-----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
       73 static files copied to  '/tmp/build_0e164445076c2ad03a67e962b1108c5b/static'.
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 54.7M
-----> Launching...
       Released v7
       https://odyssy.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

There are no errors in build log but the app is not working.
When I run `heroku run python manage.py syncdb` I face this error

`mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/media'`

The app is successfully running locally. This app uses `photologue`. When I run this locally a folder named "media" is created outside of the app directory, and this is also happening in heroku but heroku doesn't allow creating folders manually in root directory.

Is there any way to fix this?
Can I change the address of media folder in Photologue?
EDIT : Is there no way to deploy Django app with photologue on heroku?

Comment: this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716055/heroku-django-project-read-only-file-system

Comment: @NeErAjKuMaR that was helpful, thanks a lot.