# i have deployed Django project in Heroku.where users can upload images shows up for some hours after some hours images gets dont showup in screen

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

i have deployed my project in Heroku.what happens is i have form where users can upload files(images) which is reflected back to pages after being uploaded problem is those uploaded images shows on page for some hours and then images gets dont showup in screen after some hours. but again wen some users fill up the form a upload the images ,it shows up in the screen but rest of the previously uploaded images dont show up .in this newly uploaded image also disappears after some hour .  also every time i do git push heruko masters those images disappears.

you can visit the site(http://productpanditapp.herokuapp.com/)

settings.py

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'producthunt/static/')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    body = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    url = models.TextField()
    votes_total = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    hunter = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def summary(self):
        return self.body[:100]
    def short_pub_date(self):
        return self.pub_date.strftime('%b %e %Y')
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    products = Product.objects.all().order_by("-pub_date")

    query = request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
        products= products.filter(Q(title__icontains=query)|
                            Q(body__icontains=query)|
                            Q(hunter__username__icontains=query)).distinct()
    paginator = Paginator(products, 5) # Show 25 contacts per page

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    list = paginator.get_page(page)

    return render(request,'products/home.html',{'product':list})
```

home.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% if messages %}
<br>
<div class="container">
  {% for message in messages %}
  <p{% if message.tags %} class="alert alert-danger"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</p>
  {% endfor %}

{% endif %}
</div>

<br>

<div class="container">
  <form class="form-inline" method="GET" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search Product" name='q'  value="{{request.GET.q}}">

    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>

<br>

</div>
{% for pro in product %}
<div class="container pt-2">
  <div class="jumbotron p-1">
    <div class="row pt-2">
      <div class="col-2" onclick="window.location='{% url 'detail' pro.id %}';" style="cursor:pointer;">
        <img src="{{ pro.icon.url }}" height=100 width=100 class="rounded float-left"/>   #images dont show up after some hours from file is upload time
      </div>
      <div class="col-4"  onclick="window.location='{% url 'detail' pro.id %}';" style="cursor:pointer;">
        <h1>{{ pro.title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ pro.summary }}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4"  onclick="window.location='{% url 'detail' pro.id %}';" style="cursor:pointer;">

        <p><strong>Published on :</strong> {{pro.pub_date}}</p>
        <p><strong>Hunter :</strong> {{pro.hunter}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <a href="javascript:{document.getElementById('vote{{ pro.id }}').submit()}"><button class="btn btn-success  btn-block"><span class="oi oi-thumb-up"></span></span> Upvote {{pro.votes_total}}</button></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <form id="vote{{pro.id}}" action="{% url 'upvote' pro.id %}" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="hidden">
    </form>
  </div>

</div>

{% endfor %}

<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if product.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1&q={{request.GET.q}}">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ product.previous_page_number }}&q={{request.GET.q}}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ product.number }} of {{ product.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if product.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ product.next_page_number }}&q={{request.GET.q}}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ product.paginator.num_pages }}&q={{request.GET.q}}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

any help will be greatly appreciated !
Thanks in advance.!

pictures of the pages where i m facing a problem,please click the link!

[forms where images are uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuFob.png)

[main pages where images gets disappeared after some hours of being uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fm8RL.jpg)

Comment: Are you trying to store the images in the local file system? Heroku doesn't really work that way, you're expected to use S3 or some other service for that sort of thing.

Comment: can u please tell me what do you mean by local system?m confused, what i did was i made the Postgres database in heroku where every credentials for database are given by heroku itself.

Comment: You can't upload files to Heroku. They start and stop dynos as needed and any changes to the file system don't survive that process. Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/q/17716055/479863 will help.